# Issue on Docusign Admin Api getUserProfile

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignapextoolkit

Hi I am  facing an issue while loading the endpoint point `/v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users/profile`
I am getting a 404 error

[image: img_error]

Attached below screenshots for the postman response and getting `organisationId`

[image: img_postman]

Answer (score 0):

The correct baseUrl for demo Admin API is `https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/`
Try to change that and see if that works.

Comment: I Have tried by changing the baseUrl getting error message as "

{ "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://api-d.docusign.net:7731/v2/organizations/5c5811a6-7b58-4c3b-8867-f5ceb732210e/users/profile'."

}   screenshot -https://i.stack.imgur.com/P63Kx.png

Comment: what URI are you hitting? you need https://api-d.docusign.net/management//v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users/profiles and ensure you put your orgId in there.

Answer (score 0):

In order for that endpoint to work you're going to need to provide some additional parameters in the URL. For retrieving a user's profile directly, you should be able to use:
[https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{OrgID}/users/profile?email=useremail@example.com](https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/%7BOrgID%7D/users/profile?email=useremail@example.com)

The result looks like this:

```
{
    "users":  [
                  {
                      "id":  "28fbe7e4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c26569aa827c",
                      "site_id":  1,
                      "site_name":  "Demo",
                      "user_name":  "Matt_SATest_1",
                      "first_name":  "MattSAT_1",
                      "last_name":  "K",
                      "user_status":  "active",
                      "default_account_id":  "70da9c0c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7b3d6733328e",
                      "default_account_name":  "Matt K",
                      "is_organization_admin":  false,
                      "created_on":  "2020-08-25T20:38:57.533",
                      "memberships":  "",
                      "identities":  "",
                      "is_device_verification_enabled":  true
                  }
              ]
}
```

To retrieve a list of users for an org, you should be able to use:
[https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{OrgID}/users?URLParameters](https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/%7BOrgID%7D/users?URLParameters).
The URL parameters for this particular call require one of the following: account_id, organization_reserved_domain_id, or email. You're required to use at least one, but you should also be able to use more than one parameter at a time.

The result looks something like this:

```
{
    "users":  [
                  {
                      "id":  "28fbe7e4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c26569aa827c",
                      "user_name":  "Matt_SATest_1",
                      "first_name":  "Matt",
                      "last_name":  "K",
                      "user_status":  "active",
                      "email":  "email@example.com",
                      "created_on":  "2020-08-25T20:38:57.533"
                  }
              ],
    "paging":  {
                   "result_set_size":  1,
                   "result_set_start_position":  0,
                   "result_set_end_position":  0,
                   "total_set_size":  1
               }
}
```

Comment: By following the above steps  we getting below response{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "reference_id": "8573cf09-b988-4ed0-9fd9-d1b147050765"
} screenshot https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JXfZYnzXl8U/X2hNPZnSnZI/AAAAAAAAB68/Mreqmyis7Sk8JiS-698-IMkulj8OXYF1QCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-09-20.png

Comment: By following the above steps  we getting below response{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "reference_id": "8573cf09-b988-4ed0-9fd9-d1b147050765"
} screenshot https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JXfZYnzXl8U/X2hNPZnSnZI/AAAAAAAAB68/Mreqmyis7Sk8JiS-698-IMkulj8OXYF1QCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-09-20.png  
 As currently we are using sandbox trial account

Comment: What scopes are you declaring when creating your Oauth token?
A full list of the Admin API scopes can be found here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/auth